# Pandas .isin() is working for one data set but not another

Tags: pandas

I am using two different data sets (linked below) which observe geographic location. I am trying to drop all observations where State is a territory or other non-State (excluding DC). The 'State' variable/column is a non-null object in both dataframes. I include `.info()` on them to show data types and number of observations.

Earlier in my code I use `.isin()` for this purpose for a different dataframe and it works:

```
zipcodes = pd.read_csv('zipcode.csv')
zipcodes.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 42522 entries, 0 to 42521
Data columns (total 12 columns):
Zipcode                42522 non-null int64
ZipCodeType            42522 non-null object
City                   42522 non-null object
State                  42522 non-null object
LocationType           42522 non-null object
Lat                    41874 non-null float64
Long                   41874 non-null float64
Location               42521 non-null object
Decommisioned          42522 non-null bool
TaxReturnsFiled        28879 non-null float64
EstimatedPopulation    28879 non-null float64
TotalWages             28844 non-null float64
dtypes: bool(1), float64(5), int64(1), object(5)
memory usage: 2.8+ MB

drops =['PR','AP','AA','VI','GU','FM','MP','MH','PW','AS','AE']
zipcodes = zipcodes[~zipcodes['State'].isin(drops)]

zipcodes.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 41656 entries, 12 to 42521
Data columns (total 12 columns):
Zipcode                41656 non-null int64
ZipCodeType            41656 non-null object
City                   41656 non-null object
State                  41656 non-null object
LocationType           41656 non-null object
Lat                    41656 non-null float64
Long                   41656 non-null float64
Location               41656 non-null object
Decommisioned          41656 non-null bool
TaxReturnsFiled        28879 non-null float64
EstimatedPopulation    28879 non-null float64
TotalWages             28844 non-null float64
dtypes: bool(1), float64(5), int64(1), object(5)
memory usage: 3.1+ MB
```

The observations for which State is an object in the list `drops` have now been dropped.

However, when I try to do the same with another data set, the same `.isin()` code does not drop the observations for which State is in the list `drops` (I have to create the State variable by splitting an included variable and then adding it as a column, which I suspect may be causing my issue, but the resulting variable/column is still a non-null object):

```
cty_nbrs = pd.read_excel('county_adjacency.xlsx')
cty_nbrs.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
cty_nbrs.join(pd.DataFrame({'State':cty_nbrs.County.str.split(",").str.get(1)}))
cty_nbrs.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 22200 entries, 0 to 22199
Data columns (total 5 columns):
County        22200 non-null object
ctyfips       22200 non-null int32
Neighbours    22200 non-null object
nbrfips       22200 non-null int64
State         22200 non-null object
dtypes: int32(1), int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 520.4+ KB

cty_nbrs= cty_nbrs[~cty_nbrs['State'].isin(drops)]
cty_nbrs.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 22200 entries, 0 to 22199
Data columns (total 5 columns):
County        22200 non-null object
ctyfips       22200 non-null int32
Neighbours    22200 non-null object
nbrfips       22200 non-null int64
State         22200 non-null object
dtypes: int32(1), int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 520.4+ KB
```

The offending observations have not been dropped here. In case this is not evident:

```
cty_nbrs['State'].value_counts().tail()

 AS    7
 MP    6
 DC    6
 VI    5
 GU    1
Name: State, dtype: int64
```

Those realizations of State are all elements of the list `drops` which were earlier dropped from `zipcodes` using the same code. What am I missing here?

[zipcode.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AuSkk6mH5cvjCtOPRE_VDBk42htIZjPV)

[county_adjacency.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gbFH6AvCnjp7-N8qLGdT8APGDghZMBhx)

Comment: look at `cty_nbrs.State.unique()` (or just any element). One likely culprit is extra white space, so that `'AS'` is `' AS'`, which will not match. Especially since they come from different files.

Comment: ALollz, that was it. Very grateful.

Comment: yeah, you can fix it because when you are splitting the string `'something, AL'` with the `','` as the split condition, you pick up the space.